# Which Spring Maven dependency provides class MockMvc?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Which [Spring Framework](https://spring.io/) [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) dependency provides Java class [MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html)?

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test

Comment: How can any Java programmer consider this question to be off-topic?

Comment: Off-topic **for this site**: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ It's just not appropriate **here**.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis You're kidding me, right?  I didn't ask for a recommendation.  I asked for the name of the dependency which contains a particular class.  This question has a very objective (and most likely only one) answer.

Comment: I am not. The chat is better suited for such questions.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Chat?

Comment: Stack Overflow has a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) feature. (ctrl+f 'chat')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84228/discussion-between-derek-mahar-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MockMVC` is currently part of [spring-test](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test).

It moved to spring-test from [spring-test-mvc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-mvc) after Spring 3.1.

Comment: Thank you.  I just learned that [Advanced Search](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch|gav) at [The Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/) lets you search by class name.